# SugarCRM get_entry returns no fields with REST API

Tags: php, rest, sugarcrm

Calling "get_entry" on the REST webservice returns an empty result in this manner:

```
Array
(
     [entry_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 85a67fbe-ab86-597a-6bca-4f0305719543
                    [module_name] => Contacts
                    [name_value_list] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )
        )

    [relationship_list] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

My call looks like:

```
$method = 'get_entry';
$params = array(
          'module_name' => 'Contacts',
          'id' => $sugarbean_id,
      );
```

But I have absolutely no clue why i get an "empty" object as a result.
Can anyone help me or give me some pointers?

Thanks
Jeroen

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a session id for the get_entry call. You get the session id when calling the login method. See the `get_entry` [documentation](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/6.3/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.3.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.3.0.html#9000579) for more information.

Comment: I do. I have a wrapper fucntion to handle the call and set or renew the session.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It turns out that I had to explicitly specify select_fields.